# How to start process without UAC

Tags: windows-7, uac

How can I start a process without UAC in the following scenario?

Windows Vista or 7
UAC is enables
Standard user is logged in
Standard user knows admin credentials
Progrmm (running in the standard users context) starts process with the admin account.

How can I suppress the UAC? Is there any way? I imagine that this is exactly the scenario the UAC should "protect" the user from, but perhaps there is a solution

Comment: what do you mean "suppress the UAC"? Do you mean not get a UAC prompt about elevating? not elevate? not need to elevate and have things succeed even though you are not elevated?

Comment: I mean elevate without UAC prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transition from non elevated to elevated will always include a UAC prompt unless you have turned off UAC or turned the notification level way down on Windows 7.

Now if you have an elevated process, all the processes it launches will be elevated without another prompt. So for example if you start a command prompt by Right click, Run As Administrator, then everything you launch from that prompt (eg type Notepad and press Enter) will be elevated too.

Finally services are exempt from UAC, so if you have a service do what you want there will be no prompting, though of course you will need to elevate in order to install the service.

Comment: so this means it is not possible to do it without prompting from a non elevated process.

Comment: You can use Task Scheduler to do this.  See my answer.

Comment: @jason but as with installing a service, there will still be one UAC prompt in the process - in this case from the Task Scheduler, right? I think @uwe wants not just to avoid the UAC prompt each time it runs, but also as part of setting it up.

Answer (score 5):

You [can use Task Scheduler](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=616) to start the restricted program without initiating a UAC prompt on startup.

You can also [use it for normal shortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=730).

Comment: +1 Great solution! Now I can run Process Explorer from the start menu without UAC bothering every time.

Comment: You Sir are a legend!!!

Answer (score 0):

One way we have gotten around things like this in the past is to use a service as a proxy to start the process up for the user.

Comment: This is possible, but to get a service you need to elevate in the first place.

Comment: @uwe - Only when the service is first installed. If you can't get permission to do that either, then you have a human trust problem, not a computer problem.